# JQuery: Datepicker Highlighting a date Range

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, struts

I'm programming a Struts web application using JQuery 1.7 Datepicker on one of my jsps in order to implement a calendar that can highlight reminders for a user.

I have a question:

*I'd like to highlight a range of dates* in the datepicker. With my code, the Javascript console shows no errors but the range of dates is not highlighted when I log in. this is my function:

```
$(function(){

            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                flat: true,
                numberOfMonths: [1,1],
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                beforeShowDay: highlightDays
            });
```

I have an array of reminders, each reminder has 3 attributes, startDate, endDate and unit (associated unit)

On the beforeShowDay event, the function highlightDays is activated:

```
function highlightDays(date) {

     //For all reminders in the db
   for (var i = 0; i < reminders.length; i++) { 

    //If the current date in between the start and end date of reminder
      if( (new Date(reminders[i].start).getTime())  
                       <= date.getTime()                            
                      &&  (date.getTime())                           
                       <= (new Date(reminders[i].end).getTime()))  date
                { 
                  //Then highlight the current date             
                   return [true, 'ui-state-highlight',reminders[i].unit];

                }else{   //Otherwise do not highlight                          
                   return [true, ''];  
                }
           }          
      }
```

Do you have any idea what I could be doing wrong? What I've implemented so far makes sense to me so I'm not sure what could be going wrong. I would really appreciate some guidance!

Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: Are you having a problem selecting a range or using the value?

Comment: Oh thanks for commenting! Well my problem is even though I have a range (start and end date on reminders), and I'm trying to highlight the days inbetween on the calendar, it will only highlight the present day, and not the date ranges i've asked it to highlight in the highlightDays function

Comment: hiya, are you looking for something like this: http://jsbin.com/evudo , cheers

Comment: http://stephencelis.github.com/timeframe/#example_information

Comment: @MetalFrog Nice calendar you got there mate! +1 ; is it your baby? Doesn't look like datepicker or you forked datepicker code; cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I'll take a look at your sources!

Comment: Cool, let us know how it goes, cheers

Comment: @Tats_innit Nah, at work they wanted to have the 'google analytics' calendar on our stuff, spent a lot of time finding one that met our requirements. I just remember this exact request being one of the reasons we ran with it.

Comment: @MetalFrog Saweet; cheers for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this successfully with a datepicker for a from date and a datepicker for a to date, so I modified it for one datepicker. Here is the code:

```
 $(function () {
            var today = new Date();
            var thisYear = (today).getFullYear();
            var fromDate = '1/1/2000'   //this is the initial from date to set the datepicker range
            var toDate = '1/7/2000' // this is the initial to date to set the datepicker range

//... initialize datepicker....
  },
  beforeShowDay: function(date){
        //if the date is in range
        if (date >= fromDate && date <= toDate) { 
           return [true, 'ui-individual-date', '']; //applies a css class to the range
         }
         else {
            return [true, '', ''];
          }
    },
   onSelect: function (dateText, obj) {

//sets the new range to be loaded on refresh call, assumes last click is the toDate              
     fromDate = toDate; 
     toDate = new Date(dateText); 

    $(".classDp1").datepicker("refresh"); 
    $(".classDp2").datepicker("refresh"); 
  },
```

Every time you refresh the beforeShowDay function is called with the new fromDate and toDate range. Having the variables outside the function and modifying them within enables the highlighting from the css to be applied on each click.